# A pen on a table or a pen on the table

Tags: articles

Imagine you see, for example, **5 tables** in front of you and **one pen on one of them**. What would you say in this case? "I see a pen on a table" or "I see a pen on the table"? What's the difference if there are different possible ways to say this?

Comment: Using "the table" would not be used unless the table with the pen had ben previously singled out.

Comment: To answer the question directly, I wouldn't say anything.  Or I might say.  "Has anyone lost a pen?"  It is very very rare that speakers describe what they see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I see a pen on a table."

> "I see a pen on the table."

The 1st one can be used, but not the 2nd one, as there are 5 tables.

You can also say

"I see a pen on one of the tables."

You can use the 2nd example if there is only 1 table.  The 'the' in the 2nd example is a definite article, which can be used when there is no ambiguity in an identity, in this case the identity of the table with the pen.

Answer (score 0):

> A: Describe what you see.
>
> B: I see a pen on a table.

Both pen and table are new objects to you. You use "a" to introduce them.

> A: Let's move to table #2. What do you see?
>
> B: I see a pen on the table.

There is a lot of ways you can say it. You can employ adverbs of place (here and there), demonstrative determiners (this and that), the introductory subject "there" (as in "There is .." or "There are ..").

> There are 5 tables. There is a pen on one of them.
>
> I (can) see/There is a pen (over) here/there.
>
> I (can) see/There is a pen on this/that table.